# Nodejs renaming files mistake

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to rename all the .png files using the below code, but i don't see any rename changes:

```
const testFolder = "C:\\trans2\\";
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
    fs.renameSync(testFolder + file, testFolder + file.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + file.slice(1))
})
```

But when I change `rename` to:
        fs.renameSync(testFolder + file, testFolder + file.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + file.slice(1) + ".png")

Then it renames the file, but it appears to append an extra `.png` at the end of the file.

Can someone pls point out my mistake here, not able to understand how can i rectify it.

Comment: remove the + ".png" at the end

Comment: I said it above, if i don't add it, it deosnt rename @Wesgur

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code. I will say that I have had issues with the filesystem and git picking up changes when I rename files by simply changing case.

That said, I ran this script (very similar) using Node 8.8 from the directory of the files I'm attempting to change and it worked as expected:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach((file) => {
  fs.renameSync(`${__dirname}/${file}`, `${__dirname}/${file.charAt(0).toLowerCase()}${file.slice(1)}`);
});
```